# Codes are in scraped text instead of unicode characters

Tags: unicode, beautifulsoup

I'm using Beautiful Soup for extracting some texts. The program works on the command line, and when I run it it displays codes like `&#237; &#233;` etc.

How can I correct this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These codes are called HTML/XML character entities.

I haven't used Beautiful Soup before, but according to the documentation it looks like there's an option for converting character entities into Unicode characters: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Entity%20Conversion